# Show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ on $\Bbb R$ defined by $$f_n(x) = n \log \left (1 + \frac {x^2} {n} \right ),\ \ x \in \Bbb R$$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R.$

**My attempt** $:$ First I observe that the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ converges pointwise to the everywhere continuous function $f$ defined by $$f(x) = x^2,\ \ x \in \Bbb R.$$

If the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ converges uniformly to the continuous limit function $f$ on whole of $\Bbb R$ then in particular the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ converges uniformly to the continuous limit function $f$ on $[0,1].$

But then we have $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)\ dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\ dx.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Now what I found is that $$\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)\ dx = n \log \left (1 + \frac 1 n \right ) - 2n + 2n^{\frac 3 2} \arctan \left (\frac {1} {\sqrt n} \right ).$$ So we have $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x)\ dx = - \infty.$$ where as $$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\ dx = \frac 1 3.$$ which is a contradiction to $(1).$ Hence our assumption is false. So the sequence of functions $\{f_n \}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R,$ as required.

**EDIT** $:$ I found the wrong limit. By L'Hospital the limit $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \left ( \log \left (1 + \frac 1 n \right ) - 2 \right ) = 1.$$

Now what will be $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2n^{\frac 3 2} \arctan \left (\frac {1} {\sqrt n} \right )\ ?$$

By L'Hospital I got infinity. Isn't it the case? But then the overall limit becomes $+\infty.$

Comment: Oh! God. Online calculator shows that the limit is $\frac 1 3.$

Comment: Clearly, your calculations must be wrong because the integrand is positive everywhere, so the integral couldn't be negative.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I think the limit is $+\infty.$ Am I still doing any mistake?

Comment: As it turns out, $f_n$ does converge uniformly to its limit on $[0,1]$.  So, your line of reasoning is bound to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach: note that
$$
f_{n}(x) - f(x) = n \log \left (1 + \frac {x^2} {n} \right ) - \log(e^{x^2})
= \log \left( \frac{(1 + x^2/n)^n}{e^{x^2}} \right).
$$
Now, we note that for any fixed $n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(1 + x^2/n)^n}{e^{x^2}} &= 
\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 + x^2/n}{e^{x^2/n}}\right)^n = 0
\end{align}
$$
(since the numerator is a polynomial) from which we may conclude that (again, for any fixed $n$) the set $\{|f_n(x) - f(x)|: x \in \Bbb R\}$ is unbounded.  Thus, if we fix (for instance) $\epsilon = 1$, we can see that for any $n$ there exists an $x$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$, which is to say that $\|f_n - f\|_{\sup} \geq \epsilon$.

So, the sequence is not uniformly convergent.

---

Regarding your limit: with the substitution $m = \sqrt{1/n}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{m \to 0^+} 2m^{-3} \arctan \left (m \right ) &= 
2\lim_{m \to 0^+}\frac{\arctan(m)}{m^3}
= 
2\lim_{m \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{m^2 + 1}}{3m^2}
= \frac 23 \lim_{m \to 0^+} \frac{1}{m^2(m^2 + 1)} = +\infty
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice! +1 ${}$

Comment: @F Thanks! And good catch.

Comment: Can you help me in the computation of the above limit? If the given sequence of functions was uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ then the limit should be equal to $\frac 1 3.$

Comment: See my latest edit.  We could do the second limit, for instance, with two iterations of L'Hospital

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you meant the limit from my question. I'm not particularly interested in ironing that limit of integrals out. Regardless of uniform convergence, the limit has to be $\frac 13$ by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Oh, I see you  got it down to that bit with the arctan. I'll add something.

Comment: Thanks it will be really very helpful for me then.

Comment: I also got $+\infty$, not sure what's going on there. Presumably you computed the integral incorrectly

Comment: But @Om I dont know why wolfram alpha says the limit to be exactly $\frac 1 3.$

Comment: Correction: the problem is not the computation of this limit; it's the limit of the first term in the sum that you got wrong

Comment: So, the question remains: how do you find [the overall limit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infinity+2+n%5E%283%2F2%29+tan%5E%28-1%29%281%2Fsqrt%28n%29%29++%2B+n+1+%28log%28%28n+%2B+1%29%2Fn%29+-+2%29) then?  I think the easiest way is to use the Taylor series of log and arctan; you should post that as its own question if you're interested.

Comment: @Om I dont think that the limit of the first term is wrong. By L'Hospital I get $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \left ( \log \left (1 + \frac 1 n \right ) - 2 \right ) = 1.$$

Comment: @mathmaniac. "By L'Hospital" isn't enough for me to catch your mistake but in any case [you're apparently wrong](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+to+infinity++n+1+%28log%28%28n+%2B+1%29%2Fn%29+-+2%29)

Comment: @mathmaniac. Maybe this will help:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}n(\log(1 + 1/n) - 2) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log(1+1/n) - \lim_{n \to \infty}2n = 1 - \infty
$$

Comment: Oh! What a silly mistake! It's not a $\frac 0 0$ or $\frac {\infty} {\infty}$ form @Om. I tried by writing it $$\frac {\log \left (1 + \frac 1 n \right ) - 2} {\frac 1 n}$$ which is neither of this form as $n \to \infty.$ Quite convinced now! Uff.

Answer (score 2):

@mathmaniac.: (too big for a comment) using Taylor series, you rewrite $$n\log\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)-2n+2n\sqrt n\arctan\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)$$ 
as
$$n\Big(\frac{1}{n}+o\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big)-2n+2n\sqrt{n}\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}-\frac{1}{3(\sqrt n)^3}+o\Big(\frac{1}{(\sqrt n)^3}\Big)\Big)=1-\frac{2}{3}+o(1)\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{3},$$

so perhaps your mistake was to only use degree $1$ for the development of $\arctan$.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks @Ballon. +1

Comment: @mathmaniac.: You're welcome!